# Change background based on PHP value

Tags: php, html, css

This is my PHP query:

```
<?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1";
  
  if ($result = $link->query($query)) {
      $num_rows = 0;
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $num_rows++;
          
          if ($num_rows > 0) {
              // Here I want to set background image img/live-background.jpg
          } else {
              // Here I want to set background image img/blank-background.jpg
          }
      }
  }
  ?>
```

And this currently is how I set the background image:

```
<style type="text/css">
 
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("img/live-background.jpg");
    font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium", Arial, sans-serif;
}

</style>
```

How can I set different background image based on the number of rows from PHP query?

Comment: either with inline CSS (not a good practice) or assigning classes that you set depending on the rows number, e.g. .rows0 { background-image: url("img/live-background.jpg"); } rowsN { background-image: url("img/blank-background.jpg"); }

Answer (score 0):

```php
      $query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1";
      
      if ($result = $link->query($query)) {
          $num_rows = 0;
          while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              $num_rows++;
              
              if ($num_rows > 0) {
                  $background = "img/live-background.jpg";
              } else {
                  $background = "img/blank-background.jpg";
              }
          }
      }
```

Just store your wanted background in a **variable**. A **Session-Variable** is also possible, if your PHP-Script is not in the same file.

```html
<style>
    html {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-image: url("<?=$background?>");
        font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium", Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
```

Then you just echo the **variable**.

`<?=$background?>` is short for: `<?php echo $background;?>`, but only works, if your server is properly configurated.

Answer (score 0):

Using one variable `$background`

```
<?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1";
  $background = "img/live-background.jpg";
  if ($result = $link->query($query)) {
      $num_rows = 0;
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $num_rows++;
          
          if ($num_rows > 0) {
              // Here I want to set background image img/live-background.jpg
              $background = "img/live-background.jpg";
          } else {
              // Here I want to set background image img/blank-background.jpg
              $background = "img/blank-background.jpg";
          }
      }
  }
  ?>

 ....

<style type="text/css">
 
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("<?= $background; ?>");
    font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium", Arial, sans-serif;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Can I do this with color insted of image also?

Comment: @Amanda yes of course, you can do it with color too.